# Jumping to Postgres data type in DBeaver

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I'm viewing a Postgres table in DBeaver with a column that is a custom enum type. I would like to be able to jump directly to the enum type definition to see what possible values there are. How can I do this?

Comment: I'd be interested in that jump feature also... not sure it exists. I do know however that you can view the definition in the 'Data types' folder in the DB navigation pane.